# Как установить свойство transition к коду

Tags: transition

```js
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.menu > span.title');
  [].forEach.call(nodes, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      el.closest(".menu").classList.toggle("open")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.menu .title {
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .title::before {
  content: '▶ ';
  font-size: 80%;
  color: green;
}

.menu.open .title::before {
  content: '▼ ';
}

.menu.open ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Меню #1</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Краб</li>
    <li>Лобстер</li>
    <li>Тарань</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Меню #2</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Краб</li>
    <li>Лобстер</li>
    <li>Тарань</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Пытаюсь добавить свойство transition на состояние открытие/закрытие (хотелось бы плавного открытия/закрытия). Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать? Прочитал что анимация не будет работать со свойством display. Что можно сделать в моем случае, переписать код JS?

Comment: За то будет работать со свойством `opacity`

Comment: Да, спасибо за подсказку. Проверил работает. Только теперь браузер резервирует место под контент http://prntscr.com/h1ee3r

Comment: Разрешено использование JQuery?

Comment: @ikar а как по вашему провелась бы "разрешённая" анимация с display, представьте? Вот так и сделайте анимировав несколько свойств, например `opacity` и `height` , а по окончанию анимации уже можно повесить `display: none`. Я лично обожаю прятатать слайдом через `jQuery` : `element.slideUp()` - свернуть , `element.slideDown()`- развернуть, нужный display выставляется после анимации: коротко, красиво!

Answer (score 0):

В наше время очень популярен простой костыль с `max-height`. Но появляется проблема с максимальной высотой - она должна быть максимально равна реальной. Я поставил `100px`, но если у вас будут расти пункты меню - придется менять.

Так же стоит учесть, что элемент находится на странице и к нему можно достучаться табуляцией (если внутри содержатся табулируемые элементы).

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.menu > span.title');
  [].forEach.call(nodes, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      el.closest(".menu").classList.toggle("open")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .3s;
}

.menu .title {
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .title::before {
  content: '▶ ';
  font-size: 80%;
  color: green;
}

.menu.open .title::before {
  content: '▼ ';
}

.menu.open ul {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Меню #1</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Краб</li>
    <li>Лобстер</li>
    <li>Тарань</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Меню #2</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Краб</li>
    <li>Лобстер</li>
    <li>Тарань</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

---

Так же мы можем добавить поворот стрелы для большей плавности :)

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.menu > span.title');
  [].forEach.call(nodes, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      el.closest(".menu").classList.toggle("open")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .3s;
}

.menu .title {
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .title::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '▶ ';
  font-size: 80%;
  color: green;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.menu.open .title::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu.open ul {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Меню #1</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Краб</li>
    <li>Лобстер</li>
    <li>Тарань</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div id="sweeties" class="menu">
  <span class="title">Меню #2</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Краб</li>
    <li>Лобстер</li>
    <li>Тарань</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```